# Controls lose style on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, postback

I have a a page that belongs to a master page. Inside the page I have 3 controls that are inside of UpdatePanels. On a postback, those three controls lose their style sheets.

I have tried...

- Setting the script manager's EnablePartialRendering property to true
- Putting the style sheets at the top of the ASPX file
- Putting the style sheets in the header tag of the master file
- Putting a ContentPlaceHolderID on the main page and master page, with the style sheets on the ContentPlaceHolderID on the page

No matter what I do the controls lose their style sheet on postback. Any idea why?

In the head tag on the master page:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeaderContentPlaceHolder" runat="server"/>
```

On the page file, at the top:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContentPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What is the difference in the DOM or rendered HTML markup between pages?

Comment: Like night and day. I think it is actually the JS file being lost. Prepost back it's a select control with a button on top, after postback its just a select control

Comment: please can you post the code, are you including external CSS files?

Comment: Updated the original post to show the code I have now